# How to send multiple SQL query parameters in Web API GET request in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I am building an app for reporting of stock and sales summary of a hospital, and there are 19 parameters to pass in GET request of API as to show values after searching in SQL table.

I can pass 2 parameters in URL and it works, but passing 20 parameters in URL is hectic and unmanageable.

How can I send such SQL query parameters in GET request from AngularJS?

I tried passing all parameters in URL on Postman App and it works but I want to pass it as a object or such:

```js
var stockSalesSummaryPayload = {
    init: '2010/01/10',
    final: '2019/01/01',
    c_price: '0',
    XCHNGRT: '0.0',
    status: '0.0',
    firm: '0',
    userid: '0',
    all_firm: '0',
    bulk_stk: true,
    edited: true,
    super: '0',
    store: '0',
    grpid: '0',
    compcode: '0',
    ac_code: '0',
    zero: true,
    sales: true,
    bulksystem: '0',
    div_id: '0'
};

vm.fetchStockSalesSummaryList = function () {

    // CODE WORKING
    $http.get('http://192.168.50.112/medipro.api.Medipro/api/stocksalessummary?init=2015/01/10&final=2019/01/10&c_price=0&XCHNGRT=0.0&status=0.0&firm=0&userid=0&all_firm=0&bulk_stk=true&edited=true&super=0&store=0&grpid=0&compcode=0&ac_code=0&zero=true&sales=true&bulksystem=0&div_id=0')

    // CODE NOT WORKING
    $http.get('http://192.168.50.112/medipro.api.Medipro/api/stocksalessummary', stockSalesSummaryPayload)
        .then(function (result) {
            vm.stockSalesSummaryList = result.data;
            console.log(result.data);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            vm.notification = { mode: 'danger', message: 'Error: ' + error.data.message };
        });
}
```

I expect my output to come as per my query parameters.

The page looks like this:

[image: PAGE LOOKS LIKE THIS]

Comment: I have encountered this in the past, I have written one generic function that takes object & converts it into query parameters string. It's simple & most sophisticated way to achieve this objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automatically encode URL parameters, use the `params` property of the `config` object:

```
var stockSalesSummaryPayload = {
    init: '2010/01/10',
    final: '2019/01/01',
    c_price: '0',
    XCHNGRT: '0.0',
    status: '0.0',
    firm: '0',
    userid: '0',
    all_firm: '0',
    bulk_stk: true,
    edited: true,
    super: '0',
    store: '0',
    grpid: '0',
    compcode: '0',
    ac_code: '0',
    zero: true,
    sales: true,
    bulksystem: '0',
    div_id: '0'
};

var url = "http://192.168.50.112/medipro.api.Medipro/api/stocksalessummary";
var config = { params: stockSalesSummaryPayload };

$http.get(url, config)
.then(function (result) {
    vm.stockSalesSummaryList = result.data;
    console.log(result.data);
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    vm.notification = { mode: 'danger', message: 'Error: ' + error.data.message };
});
```

The AngularJS framework will automatically add the search parameters to the URL with reserved characters properly [percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read the AngularJs documentation at [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

The problem with your code is that you should use the 'params' configuration that the api gives to you. So your code should become something like this:

```
$http.get(url, {params: {init: stockSalesSummaryPayload.init}}).then( ... and so on... )
```

Answer (score 0):

For sending parameters as a request payload (or we can just say body), you need to convert your request from **GET to POST**. As we can't send any data in payload for GET request as per HTTP Protocols. So, also you have to convert in your backend codebase also for accepting post request and payload.

Or you can use params, if don't want to change any backend.

```
$http.get(<url>, {
    params: <your request data in JSON format>
});
```

Edit:

As per angular js docs:

**params – {Object.} – Map of strings or objects which will be serialized with the paramSerializer and appended as GET parameters.**

Thanks!

Comment: i can send such request directly in URL

Comment: Yes, you can but angular provides us the feasible and modular way to do it. but can't send data directly as paramter in get request, you have to wrap the data in {params} field.